# Writing command output to file

Tags: shell

I have a problem trying to write the output of a shell command to a file.

This works

```
cssbeautify basket.css > file.css
```

This doesn't. basket.css has now no content

```
cssbeautify basket.css > basket.css
```

Is that a normal behavior? How to get around it?

Edit: Here is the command I'm using to beautify all the files in the folder. You might find it useful.

```
for f in *;
do cssbeautify $f > temp_file && mv temp_file $f;
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use a file as "pattern" and redirect to it.

Use for example:

```
cssbeautify basket.css > temp_file && mv temp_file basket.css
```

It will create a `temp_file` and -in case the first command runs successfully- then will overwrite it to `basket.css`.

Answer (score 2):

cssbeautify reads from `basket.css`, beautifies it and writes to `STDOUT`.

By using `> basked.css` you instruct the shell to write the output to `basked.css`. Before that the file content is cleared. cssbeautify thus reads an empty file and outputs an empty file.

So yes this is the normal behavior. You could write to a temporary file and `mv` it afterwards.